# New User Notification - Setting Email

Tags: admin, email, notifications

When a new user registers an email is sent to my email address. When I created the site the first admin account was mine using email address (a@a.com)

I want to change which email is sent a new user notification.

Under Settings > General there is a field named E-mail Address. I have this set to a different email address (b@b.com) but it is still sending emails to me (a@a.com)

Documentation says the email notification is sent to the Admin email. On this site we have three admin accounts. The b@b.com is not associated to an admin account.

Documentation not very clear in this instance.

What is the process to change this or have I some plugin interfering and causing a problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme. If this is not the case, then we can look further into it. But from what [`wp_new_user_notification()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_new_user_notification/) source shows, it's just using whatever you set as `admin_email` option.

Comment: Not able to test this at the moment. Are you able to clarify wha the admin_email is. Is it a) the email set in Settings > General b) the first admin email used to create the site c) other

Comment: Just go home and in front of a computer :) Then just dump the contents of `get_option( 'admin_email' );` in the footer.

Comment: Thanks - live site for an old client (receiving their emails). Bit long-winded to clone to local. Will output option as recommended. Cheers

Comment: Ok, can confirm get_option( 'admin_email' ) is set to the email address in Settings > General. But emails still sent to the other email address...

Comment: Have you done like asked in the first comment?

Answer (score -1):

do you have a hand coded theme?
A while ago I did a theme for a friend and insted of any plugins, costum post types, etc. I created a page manually and made a sign up form. This is how my form was set up:

START OF PHP CODE!

`$to = 'email@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'Your desired subject';
$option1= $_POST['option1'];
$option2= $_POST['option2'];
$option3= $_POST['option3'];`

$body = <<< EMAIL
The desired message that will be sent to the given email.
Option 1: $option1
Option 2: $option2
Option 3: $option3
EMAIL;

$headers = "From: $email";
if($_POST) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
}
END OF PHP CODE!

```
<label for="option1">Option 1</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="option1" id="option1" placeholder="Option 1" />

<label for="option2">Option 2</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="option2" id="option2" placeholder="Option 2" />

<label for="option3">Option 3</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="option2" id="option3" placeholder="Option 3" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am talking about the automatic notifications and not a sign up form.